# How to use ExpectJ in Jython?

Tags: java, python, jython, expectj

In our company we use Jython for some reason. I need to extend it with the ExpectJ, but I could not figure out how to do it.

I managed to download the **expectj-2.0.7.jar**, **expectj-2.0.7-sources.jar** and **expectj-2.0.7-javadoc.jar** files and made them accessible to Jython and Java itself as well.

So I can import it in my python script and JVM also finds the jars (by using a [classpath loader hack](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/appendixB.html#working-with-classpath)). But according to [ExpectJ's docs](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html), something is still wrong.

```
import expectj

ex = expectj.ExpectJ()                       # I cannot use the second form of the
                                             # constructor where I can pass a timeout
                                             # parameter

sh = ex.spawn(targetshell, 22, usr, passw)   # There is no spawn method in 
                                             # ExpectJ - but why???
```

This is where I'm getting stuck. Why doesn't the ExpectJ object have a `spawn` method? Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is to ensure that spawned process completes before executing the next command. It guarantees the cycle 'send - expect - wait for completion of the command sent in send' and then 'send again - expect again - wait for completion' .

In order to wait for command prompt to finish executing the spawned process, use `shell.expect("")`. If in case there are further expectJ send and expect commands after this, sequential execution can be ensured. If there is no `shell.expect("")` the next step `shell.send("exit\n")` is executed without waiting for the completion of the process that it has already spawned, in the following case scp command is put to completion before next command is issued.

```
import expectj
expectinator = expectj.ExpectJ();
shell = expectinator.spawn(expectj.SshSpawn(host_name, 22, usr_name, ssh_pwd));
shell.send("scp -r src:usr:dest" + "\r")
shell.expect(remote_box_usr + "'s password:");
shell.send(ssh_pwd + "\r");
shell.expect("");
shell.send("exit\n");
shell.expectClose();
```